# Como autenticar Json com php passando header

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho a seguinte documentação, gostaria de saber como fazer a autenticação, 
e se possível onde eu consigo material de estudo que tenha exemplo para realizar uma tal autenticação.

http://docs.00k.io/v2/

URL BASE:
Todas as chamadas deste modulo devem partir da seguinte URL Base.
http://api.00k.srv.br/

AUTENTICAÇÃO:
Para acessar a API é necessário passar dois headers, são eles:

```
Authorization: {String}
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não conheço essa API, mas a header eu creio que é assim:

```
 Authorization: Basic [login e senha em base64]
```

**Se for** do tipo `Basic`, para resumir ele funciona assim:

```
Authorization: [tipo] [credenciais]
```

Na doc fala isto:

> Cada loja possui sua própria chave de autenticação a ser utilizada no header HTTP Authorization, que deve ser solicitada ao seu gestor de contas na 00K.

Então creio que o gestor possa informar se é de fato `Basic`, se for basic e esta usando PHP pode usar assim:

```
$usuario = 'usuario';
$senha = 'senha';

$header = 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($usuario . ':' . $senha);
```

Mas isso é como eu já disse, é somente ser for do tipo `Basic` se for outro tipo esqueça, não é assim que irá funcionar.

Acaso for realmente `Basic` siga alguns exemplos abaixo:

### Usando Basic com file_get_contents

```
$usuario = 'usuario';
$senha = 'senha';

$url = 'http://api.00k.srv.br/';

$header = 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($usuario . ':' . $senha) . "\r\n"
          'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
                  'header' => $header
              )
    )
);
$homepage = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($data); //Visualiza a resposta
```

### Usando Basic com curl

```
$usuario = 'usuario';
$senha = 'senha';

$url = 'http://api.00k.srv.br/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data === false) {
    echo 'Erro ao executar o CURL: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpcode !== 200) {
        echo 'Erro ao requisitar o servidor';
    }
}

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data); //Visualiza a resposta
```